# In which versions of Latin Vulgate this phrase "as I also am of Christ" present?

Tags: 1-corinthians, latin-vulgate, douay-rheims

1 Corinthians 4:16, (DRB):

> Wherefore I beseech you, be ye followers of me, **as I also am of Christ.**

This phrase "as I also am of Christ" present in Douay-Rheims Bible, I looked a version of Latin Vulgate, this extra phrase not found.

But surely DRB has this phrase from a version of Latin Vulgate.

So, in which versions of Latin Vulgate this phrase present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1 Cor 4:16 we have the Greek text:

> παρακαλῶ οὖν ὑμᾶς, μιμηταί μου γίνεσθε

I would translate this as: "Therefore, I exhort you, become imitators of me."

The Jerome Latin text is:

Rogo ergo vos, imitatores mei estote (= I beg you to imitate my example)

The Clementine vulgate text says:

Rogo ergo vos, imitatores mei estote, **sicut et ego Christi**. (= I beg you to imitate my example **as I am of Christ**)

Note that the Clementine text has the extra phrase in bold above.  I do not know how this has been added to the Greek text.  However, just three MSS, 104 (1087 AD), 614 (13th cent), 629 (14th cent) also have this phrase added in the Greek.  It appears that a scribe decided to add this phrase about the middle of the 11th century.

Comment: There is a legitimate precedent for this addition in 1 Cor 11:1 - "Be imitators of me, as I am of Christ."  This is not contested in the text.